# How to display Reportviewer in other system?

Tags: c#

i am using WinForm App. C#2010 with 4.0 ,after deploying application to another computer i have error i have copied all references along with reports which i used but still error in uploading report."Could not load file or assembly error
microsoft.reportviewer.processing object model version = 10.0.0.0,
culture = neutral"

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/138661) if it solved your problem. That way, you signal to the community that the question is no longer open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the **Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 Redistributable Package** on your client's machine:

> Microsoft Report Viewer control enables applications that run on the .NET Framework to display reports designed using Microsoft reporting technology. This redistributable package contains Windows and Web versions of the Report Viewer.

Download link:

- [Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6442)